# How to include MCC and PRC evaluation in weka classification elevator using WEKA 3.6.10 GUI

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am Using latest version of weka 3.6.10 GUI, after classification i am getting performance evaluation results  without MCC and PRC measure. How can i get or include these two values during evaluation (a sample evaluation results listed below provided by a tutorial)

Getting this:

```
TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure    ROC Area   Class
0.985    0.374    0.972      0.985    0.978        0.974      Alive
0.626    0.015    0.753      0.626    0.684        0.974      Dead
0.959    0.349    0.957      0.959    0.958        0.974
```

expecting this:

```
TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
0.985    0.374    0.972      0.985    0.978      0.665    0.974     0.998     Alive
0.626    0.015    0.753      0.626    0.684      0.665    0.974     0.775     Dead
0.959    0.349    0.957      0.959    0.958      0.665    0.974     0.982
```

Kindly help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUPRC and the MCC are only available in the Weka Dev Lib (v3.7.10)

Comparing the [stable](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html) and [dev](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html) doc of the Evaluation class:
The `areaUnderPRC()` and `matthewsCorrelationCoefficient()` methods are missing in the stable lib. So your output (which uses the `toClassDetailsString()` method) cannot include those values.

Maybe you could try to manually replace the stable with [dev lib](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/downloading.html) in your Weka GUI system.